# How can i click a button that meet some requirements? - Selenium

Tags: python, python-3.x

sorry for the question but i'm learning to code, i'm a newbie.

i need to create a button that click the button only if some requirements are meets.

Problem is that this code change everytime that i click in this:
Button activated:

```
mt-10 button small js-filter-momo
```

Button deactivated:

```
mt-10 button small js-filter-momo button--light-outline
```

I need to click the button on this page only if the button is deactivated, so:

```
mt-10 button small js-filter-momo button--light-outline
```

if the button is already activated i need to move on, what can i do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming what you have provided is a class, you may try with the `try/except` block.

```
try:
    driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//*[@class='mt-10 button small js-filter-momo button--light-outline']").click()
except:
    pass
```